# CSS will not load Craft 3 + MAMP

Tags: craft3, css, mamp

I'm a UX designer with some front end skills (though a complete novice with server config and Craft). I'm hoping someone can help me with something that seems rather basic.

**Setup:** 
Mac Book Pro running High Sierra (10.13.5).
Using MAMP 4.4.1 (free version)
PHP 7.2.1, MySQL, and Craft 3.
The site loads in a browser when I visit: http://localhost:8888/.

My craft files are here: Macintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.

The template file in question is here: Macintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/templates/_layouts/base.html

In the base.html file, in the head section, I am attempting to link to several CSS files. Here's the entire head section:

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      {% css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ siteUrl }}src/css/typeplate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ siteUrl }}src/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ siteUrl }}src/css/screen.css">
      {% endcss %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

The CSS files in question are here: Macintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/src/css.

**The Problem:**
When I load the home page, the CSS does not load.

**Things I've Tried:**

- I've tried removing the siteURL bit, and just hardcoding things
  instead (like this: http://localhost/src/css/typeplate.css), and I
  get 404 errors for the 3 css files under the network tab in Chrome developer tools.
- I've tried removing the {% css } brackets around the stylesheet links, and the network tab in Chrome dev tools just tells me "failed" when the links are hard coded. When the links have {{ siteUrl}} in them, I can see the browser looking for the files at www.mywebsite.com/src/css/typeplate.css. But the files aren't currently there - this is a local dev site only.
- I've tried changing the dev siteUrl in general.php from "null" to
  "http://localhost/", and the web page stops loading altogether.
- I've tried different hard coded URL's, like
  (../src/css/typeplate.css).
- I've searched StackExchange for similar problems, but I can't seem to make sense of any of the answers.

Can anyone help? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: "I've tried changing the dev siteUrl in general.php from "null" to "http://localhost/"" - try changing that to 'http://localhost:8888'. If it doesn't load, set `'devMode' => true` in your `craft/config/general.php` file, reload the page and see if you get an error.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, Brad. I tried both things, and the home page will not load. It says "This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Strike my previous comment, Brad. I had a syntax problem (forgot the comma at the end of the row!). So, now there's no error. However, I still have the wrong file path, apparently. The browser is looking at http://localhost:8888/src/css/typeplate.css, and it says 404 for the CSS file in the network tab in Chrome developer tools. And when I put that file path into the browser's address bar directly, I get a craft 404 page that's got a bunch of stuff on it that I can't hardly make any sense of. What would be the file path for my src folder?

Comment: Update: after some searching, I decided to move my src/ folder into the web/ folder, since Craft seems to be looking only there and not at anything above that directory. Then, my CSS links were updated to relative paths like this: src/css/typeplate.css. And that worked.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted, Chris... would you mind adding your solution as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I decided to move my src/ folder into the web/ folder, since Craft seems to be looking only there and not at anything above that directory. Then, my CSS links were updated to relative paths like this: src/css/typeplate.css. And that worked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution Chris!

If you're wondering _why_ many projects have CSS files in the /src folder, it's because often these days, people use an automated workflow to combine and compress multiple CSS/JS files from /src, and then place the result in /web

One of the tools for this is called Gulp (there's also Grunt), and https://nystudio107.com/blog/a-gulp-workflow-for-frontend-development-automation gives a great overview of how it works.